# Excel VBA - Formula with unknown size of the table

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm facing a problem unknown to me so far.
I want to run XLOOKUP (via VBA macro) and the size of the table changes weekly. I have entered a general range from 3 to 30000, but I would like it to be dynamic.
Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet ... despite search

Do any of you have an idea or an approach?

Thanks in advance for your help and support

```
Sub XVerweisIP()
Dim LR As Long

With ActiveSheet
LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'letzte Zeile der Spalte
    .Range("U3:U" & LR).FormulaLocal = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS(AG3;Update!$AG$3:$AG$30000;Update!$U$3:$U$30000);"""")"
    .Range("V3:V" & LR).FormulaLocal = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS(AG3;Update!$AG$3:$AG$30000;Update!$V$3:$V$30000);"""")"
    .Range("W3:W" & LR).FormulaLocal = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS(AG3;Update!$AG$3:$AG$30000;Update!$W$3:$W$30000);"""")"
    .Range("X3:X" & LR).FormulaLocal = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS(AG3;Update!$AG$3:$AG$30000;Update!$X$3:$X$30000);"""")"
    .Range("U3:X30000") = Range("U3:X30000").Value 'hier bis zum Ende der Tabelle
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the same approach you used with `LR`...

Comment: If you don't have any other data above or below your lookup range, you could just do the lookup on the entire column like `Update!$AG:$AG`. Another option, you could format your lookup range as a table first, that way you don't have to specify the first and last rows.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick help and  support.

Answer (score 1):

### A VBA Lookup: Becoming Dynamic

[image]

- If the code is in the workbook containing these worksheets and you're doing this to a single worksheet, then I can't see a reason why you would use `ActiveSheet` instead of specifying (referencing) the worksheet with e.g.

  ```
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ```

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub XVerweisIP()
    
    Dim slRow As Long, dlRow As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Parent.Worksheets("Update")
            slRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        dlRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("U3:X" & dlRow)
            ' Default (Any Locale)
            .Formula _
                = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($AG3,Update!$AG$3:$AG$" & slRow _
                & ",Update!U$3:U$" & slRow & "),"""")"
            ' German Locale
            '.FormulaLocal _
                = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS($AG3;Update!$AG$3:$AG$" & slRow _
                & ";Update!U$3:U$" & slRow & ");"""")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**A Study (Digging Deeper)**

```vb
Sub XVerweisIP_Study()
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Update"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "AG3" ' (last row)
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "AG" ' 2. ... here...
    Const SRC_FIRST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "U" ' 3. ... and return these...
    
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A3" ' (last row)
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "AG" ' 1. Find a match of this...
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMNS As String = "U:X" ' 4. ... here.
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim dflCell As Range, drrg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
        drCount = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If drCount < 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set dflCell = .EntireRow.Columns(DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
        Set drrg = .EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COLUMNS).Resize(drCount)
    End With
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = dws.Parent.Worksheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, srrg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set slrg = .EntireRow.Columns(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN).Resize(srCount)
        Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_FIRST_RETURN_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    ' Default (Any Locale)
    
    Dim Formula As String:
    Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(" & dflCell.Address(0) _
        & ",'" & SRC_SHEET & "'!" & slrg.Address & ",'" & SRC_SHEET & "'!" _
        & srrg.Address(, 0) & "),"""")"
    
    Debug.Print Formula
    
    drrg.Formula = Formula

    ' German Locale

'    Dim FormulaLocal As String:
'    FormulaLocal = "=WENNFEHLER(XVERWEIS(" & dflCell.Address(0) _
'        & ";'" & SRC_SHEET & "'!" & slrg.Address & ";'" & SRC_SHEET & "'!" _
'        & srrg.Address(, 0) & ");"""")"
'
'    Debug.Print FormulaLocal
'
'    drrg.FormulaLocal = FormulaLocal

    drrg.Value = drrg.Value

    MsgBox "Data looked up (verwiesen).", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and the whole code
Appreciated

Comment: Hello, I have one more question about your code.
So far it worked as it should. Now, unfortunately, it has been shown that the data is not ALL transferred from the sheet update to the master.
I currently have about 21000 lines. When running the code (A Study (Digging Deeper) some fields between column U and X are left blank. However, if I filter and run your code again, data is entered.
If I then take out this filter again, the fields are displayed empty again.
Would you like to look again where the error could be? Unfortunately I can't find it.

Comment: For your information: In column A and AG there are no blank lines between 3 and 21000.

Thanks in advance for all your efforts